# Type inference with a Union types when accessing object by key/square brackets

Tags: typescript, union, type-inference

I have a union type that is set in an object array type where I am dynamically looping after and using. When I set the object as a variable, check with an if case its type and then access it, the type is correctly picket from the union type. However if I access the object dynamically with square brackets, the type is still union type.

```
enum types {
  FOO = 'FOO',
  BAR = 'BAR',
  FAS = 'FAS',
}

// example objects
type TObject_FOO = {
  id: string
  type: types.FOO
}
type TObject_BAR = {
  id: string
  type: types.BAR
}

type TObject_FAS = {
  id: string
  type: types.FAS
}

// utility class
type TPossibleObjectType = TObject_FOO | TObject_BAR | TObject_FAS

type Example<T = TPossibleObjectType> = {
  id: string
  currentObjectId: string
  list: Record<string, T>
}

const dummy: Example<TObject_FOO | TObject_BAR> = {
  id: 'ex',
  currentObjectId: 'object_foo',
  list: {
    object_foo: {
      id: 'object_foo',
      type: types.FOO,
    },
    object_bar: {
      id: 'object_bar',
      type: types.BAR,
    },
  },
}

// This works as expected
const test = dummy.list.test
if (test.type === types.BAR) {
  // since we are checking type from enum
  // typeof assign here is infered as TObject_BAR, which is correct
  const assign = test
}

// This doesnt work
if (dummy.list[dummy.currentObjectId].type === types.BAR) {
  // type of assign is still union type
  // which is: types.FOO | types.BAR
  const assign = dummy.list[dummy.currentObjectId].type
}
```

I have tried different options and tried to search it properly, but since I can't even explain the problem properly, I could not find a proper solution. I have tried different/similar solutions I found, tried to write a mapper function as well, but lost it totally after a while. It feels like this is either not supported or I am doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't know that both places where you do `dummy.list[dummy.currentObjectId]` will be the same object. Such a thing is hard for the compiler to track, especially with dynamic property access.

But if you just save a reference of the object to a constant, then Typescript can narrow the type of that object just fine.

```
const obj = dummy.list[dummy.currentObjectId]
if (obj.type === types.BAR) {
  const assign = obj.type // types.BAR
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBALgngB2AZygbwFBSgMQPJ5QC8UA5PnqQDRZQBCAggErFmNPW04MDKr5vTgF8MGAPRiowAB4BDCAgA2wKAHsARgCtgAYxjIM8JFAAqeLbpgB9Cq0zYAlgBMAXFGQwATg5ABzWkbAboHIAHQUGCKBpubaelbsdrTObh7efgGIQbBZYeyRotFmFvHcfCT2UCnuXj7+2IHBueG8BeKSYDAOig7wUDqKssgGRQAKqsMO6sqxliZZrMVx1rYAPjEl1onrS5Y2rYYLAKJyCsoAPCaL45PTwLN680gAfEmOrjXp9f1gnp6gMAeMAAkh80nVaD0PG4mLpVJ4nOdwX4qKZnm0dKoQB4oE5IBA4G4TvIlMBLkCbAQoDsKexXhVkh9SDJONgdL9-iBAZtQW5SBpllYAGaqVSsqBQmBuSrYAV7EWqaW0bDvPly+IK8UqnJIJpIMIUGjaoRGlXq6zqWSeJXa1Vkc1WS2eLUqxo6lChdim7Am2i+kQYTHYmCwFAhkh4iAE0KS0IwMMYBxCqAACnjHjjCyI2fdeWYAEp0LQgzihsgHL4QKx0zBaBJtQA9AD8GKxOIFrEj0clAG0u3BQuy-gCgaCALqJ5MpgWZ4zZkghT0FotstshssVqskGeBOuSFXNyJAA)